# Vue.js orderBy does not work properly with uppercase and lowercase

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on an application with Laravel 5.2 + Vuejs + Vueify and I have an array of object listed on a table but I have 2 problems.

**1. orderBy works in separated with uppercase and lowercase**

The orderBy is applying separated with record where the first letter is uppercase and lower case!

**2. specials caracteres on the filter field**

Typing "**Á**gua" on the filter field does not find the "Agua" result because of the acute accent on the letter A and I would like to ignore the accent... is that possible?

**JS File**

```
Vue.filter('pmlOrderBy', function(arr, sortKey, reverse) {

  if (!sortKey) {
    return arr;
  }
  var order = (reverse && reverse < 0) ? -1 : 1;

  // sort on a copy to avoid mutating original array
  return arr.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    if (sortKey !== '$key') {
      if (Vue.util.isObject(a) && '$value' in a) a = a.$value;
      if (Vue.util.isObject(b) && '$value' in b) b = b.$value;
    }
    a = Vue.util.isObject(a) ? Vue.parsers.path.getPath(a, sortKey) : a;
    b = Vue.util.isObject(b) ? Vue.parsers.path.getPath(b, sortKey) : b;

    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();

    //         return a.localeCompare(b) * order;

    return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? order : -order;
  });
});


new Vue({

  el: 'body',

  data: {
    record: {},
    selected: [],
    list: [{
      name: 'Google',
      id: 1,
    }, {
      name: 'Água',
      id: 2,
    }, {
      name: 'Agua Branca',
      id: 3,
    }, {
      name: 'first time',
      id: 4,
    }, {
      name: 'boston',
      id: 5,
    }, {
      name: 'Type',
      id: 6,
    }, {
      name: 'Facebook',
      id: 7,
    }, ],
    sortProperty: 'name',
    sortDirection: 1,
  },

  methods: {

    sort: function(property) {
      this.sortProperty = property;
      this.sortDirection = (this.sortDirection == 1) ? -1 : 1;
    },

  }

});
```

**HTML File**

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" v-model="textFilter" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to filter...">
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">Click at the TH to sort</div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th @click="sort('id')" style="cursor: pointer;">Id</th>
        <th @click="sort('name')" style="cursor: pointer;">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="r in list | filterBy textFilter | pmlOrderBy sortProperty sortDirection">
        <td class="text-center" style="width:90px">{{ r.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/sakaho/edit?html,js,output)

**==== EDITED ====**

As Taylor and RainningChain helped me bellow we almost got there!

I found [this article](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/case-insensitive-orderby-filter-with-vuejs) and updated the code and the JS Bin above but the problem now is:

- It is sort properly but if I try to sort other column clicking on another TH it brakes.
- The problem with special caracteres still there =/

Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you would have to create your own filter.

Extending Vue's `orderBy` filter, this would be a functional solution to both of your problems.

```
// This was originally copied from the Vue source
// File: src/filters/array-filters.js
function orderByWords (arr, sortKey, reverse) {
  arr = convertArray(arr)
  if (!sortKey) {
    return arr
  }
  var order = (reverse && reverse < 0) ? -1 : 1
  // sort on a copy to avoid mutating original array
  return arr.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
    if (sortKey !== '$key') {
      if (isObject(a) && '$value' in a) a = a.$value
      if (isObject(b) && '$value' in b) b = b.$value
    }
    a = isObject(a) ? getPath(a, sortKey) : a
    b = isObject(b) ? getPath(b, sortKey) : b
    return a.localeCompare(b) * order
  })
}
```

The meat of the filter is this snippet here:
`a.localeCompare(b)`

The `String.prototype.localeCompare` method compares two strings and returns an integer value based on whether the initial string (`a`) comes before or after the compared string (`b`).

**UPDATE**

It turns out the filter was breaking because `Number.prototype.localeCompare` doesn't exist...who knew?

So we can use a little type-casting trickery to get this to work on anything.

```
Vue.filter('pmlOrderBy', function (arr, sortKey, reverse) {
    if (!sortKey) {
        return arr;
    }
    var order = (reverse && reverse < 0) ? -1 : 1;

    // sort on a copy to avoid mutating original array
    return arr.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
        if (sortKey !== '$key') {
            if (Vue.util.isObject(a) && '$value' in a) a = a.$value;
            if (Vue.util.isObject(b) && '$value' in b) b = b.$value;
        }
        a = Vue.util.isObject(a) ? Vue.parsers.path.getPath(a, sortKey) : a;
        b = Vue.util.isObject(b) ? Vue.parsers.path.getPath(b, sortKey) : b;

        return (''+a).localeCompare((''+b)) * order;
    });
});
```

The key line is the last line of the filter. `(''+a).localeCompare` will coerce `a` into a `String` and then call the `localeCompare` method.

Comment: Worth mentionning custom filters can be created via `Vue.filter(name,customOrderByFunc)`.

Comment: Guys I still have problem! I updated the question! Do you have any idea? @rainningchain

Comment: @GustavoBissolli I've updated my response to include an updated filter for you.

Comment: Great job @TaylorGlaeser! Any ideia how to solve the filter issue? On the JS Bin would be great typing "Agua" and find the "Água" result! Do you know any trick to do it? I already marked your answer as Correct because my biggest problem is solved =) thanks to you!

Comment: @GustavoBissolli I would probably have to recommend offloading that work to an NPM module. Something like https://github.com/andrewrk/node-diacritics would be a good option. You would have to run each option through a filter that compares the normalized string to your search.

Comment: Good advice @TaylorGlaeser! I am trying to extends filterBy vue.js and if I need I will open a new topic!! Thanks man!